# Polymorphism missunderstanding

Tags: java, reference, polymorphism

this is my code:

```
abstract class A{
public void sth1(){}
//code
}

public class B extends A{
public void sth2(){}
}

public class Test{
public static void main(String[] args){
A testObject=new B();
testObject.sth1(); // this line works 
testObject.sth2();  // at this line my code does not work
}
```

I'm trying to learn java by myself. I have trouble with this example. How can i fix that ?

Comment: The declared type of `testObject` needs to be `B`.  (Or you can use a dynamic cast: `((B)testObject).sth2()`).

Comment: I would suggest to go the [guided self-learning route](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).